# How to replace a slash and a apostrophe correctly with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace/remove a backslash and an apostrophe (\') in specific ID

HTML

```
<div id="here">
  Example \' Example
</div>
```

I wrote this Script:

```
var wert = document.getElementById("here");
function myFunction() {
    here.innerHTML = here.innerHTML.replace('\\['"]', '');
}
myFunction();
```

It doesn't seem to work

Comment: currently that is a string, not a regex literal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use *string* parameter instead regex, so you find in source string sequence

```
\['"]
```

For using regex, your code should be like this

```
here.innerHTML.replace(/[\\'"]/, '')
```

and possibly *g* modificator

```
here.innerHTML.replace(/[\\'"]/g, '')
```

```js
console.log('src:', 'text\\text\'text"');
console.log('dest:', 'text\\text\'text"'.replace(/[\\'"]/g, ''));
```

```js
document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = document.getElementById("here").innerHTML.replace(/[\\'"]/g, '')
```

```html
<div id="here">
  Example \' Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

You can write your own function to do this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement); 
};
```

Then

```
here.innerHTML.replaceAll('\\').replaceAll("'");
```

should do the trick.

Depending on the kind of strings you have, you might need to escape the "search" string in advance:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```